# Casting base type to derived type in Golang

Tags: go

I'm not entirely sure how to ask this question - I have a type that I 'derived' from another using the standard golang type keyword:

```
type EWKBGeomPoint geom.Point
```

I want to essentially 'override' the geom.Point Scan() and Value() functions, so I have the following function:

```
func (g *EWKBGeomPoint) Scan(input interface{}) error {
    gt, err := ewkbhex.Decode(string(input.([]byte)))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    g = gt.(*geom.Point) // error here

    return nil
}
```

However, when I run this, it has an interface conversion error:

```
interface conversion: geom.T is *geom.Point, not *models.EWKBGeomPoint
```

I don't understand why this is the case - I have seen multiple code samples now that allow this behavior. Also it would intuitively seem to me that it *should* work, because they are basically the same types with all of the same underlying variables and functions.

How can I convert this type to the target type?

[Link to go-geom docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/twpayne/go-geom/encoding/ewkbhex#Decode)

Go version is go1.13.4 linux/amd64

Comment: You should typecast to its original type before coverting to some other types (although it is alias). Example: ```(*models.EWKBGeomPoint)(gt.(*geom.Point))```

Comment: This is a new „named type“ where the „underlying type“ is geom.point. Note that there are no type casts in Go, only type conversions. Invest some time and read the language spec: ist is Short, understandable, and informative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot override functions in Go.

If you define a new type like:

```
type EWKBGeomPoint geom.Point
```

Then `EWKBGeomPoint` is a new type containing the same member fields of `geom.Point`, but none of its methods.

If you define a new type by embedding:

```
type EWKBGeomPoint struct {
   geom.Point
}
```

Then, `EWKBGeomPoint` is a new type embedding a `geom.Point`. All member variables *and functions* of `geom.Point` are also defined for `EWKBGeomPoint`.

If you use your declaration, you can convert the result:

```
g = (*models.EWKBGeomPoint)(gt.(*geom.Point))
```

If you use type embedding, you can assign it to the embedded point:

```
g.Point = *gt.(*geom.Point)
```

However, either case you did not override the `Scan` function, you defined a `Scan` function for the new type.

Answer (score 0):

You can only [type assert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) what's in the interface, so you have no choice but to use `gt.(*geom.Point)`, but you may [convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) the result:

```
g = (*models.EWKBGeomPoint)(gt.(*geom.Point))
```